# I can't get return value in PHP

Tags: php

I can't get the return value! The Output appears 'ERROR'.

```
$c = new List();
$result = $c->create();

if( $result == "a"){
   echo("A");                   
}else if($result == "b"){
   echo("B");
}else{
   echo("ERROR");
}

class List{

    function create(){

       // $rVal = ...

       if($rVal == 1){
           return "a";
       }else if($rVal == 2){
           return "b";
       }
    }
}
```

when I change return to echo, the output appears 'aERROR'. I don't understand. create function works but the return value is not true. Can anyone help me please?
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($result)` to see what you are getting back?

Comment: If you change `return` to `echo`, you are not actually **returning** anything

Comment: Maybe `$rVal` is neither `1` nor `2`.

Comment: What is `$rVal` do you pass it or assign a value.  Seems like code is doing just what you told it.

Comment: print_r($result) is returning "aERROR"

Comment: @Think also the `create()` function doesn't **always** return...

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Actually, it does. The implicit return value is `null`.

Comment: @Antuan, if you don't specify a return value, `$result` will be evaluated as `false` (null).

Comment: Right, didn't think of that.

Comment: var_dump($result) shows "NULL ERROR"

Comment: I need a return value as a string

Comment: @MatteoTassinari, but the author said he's changing `return` to `echo`! So it will return `null` regardless the value of `$rVal`

Comment: If you read what he says about changing `return` to `echo`, you'll notice that what's echoed is **"aERROR"**, meaning inside `create()`, it's echoing "a", so `$rVal` has to have a value of 1. Then it's returning null so the other `if` is echoing "ERROR". The real problem here is that the first `if` is not echoing "A" like it should be when he's returning "a" instead of echoing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code below is correct, then you are not setting `$rVal`.  The assignment seems commented out:

```
class List{

    function create(){

       // $rVal = ...

       if($rVal == 1){
           return "a";
       }else if($rVal == 2){
           return "b";
       }
    }
}
```

So, nothing (null) will be returned by `create()` call... which is interpreted as false.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did not read that the author said: "when I change return to echo"...

Comment: My assumption was he meant he changed his code to echo the return.  Considering no where in `create()` is the word ERROR shown.  But, just my assumption.

Comment: "when I change return to echo, the output appears 'aERROR'" means he's changing the return statements in `create()` to echoes. It's echoing 'a', meaning `$rVal == 1` and it should normally return "a" there. Then, since it's obviously not returning anything, it's getting to the `if` where it echoes "ERROR" because of `$result` being null. There's just no newline between those two echoes.